# Laravel 5.4 eloquent one to many relationship data fetching

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have two tables. 1.products 2.product_images.

Field of products Table: id,product_name,created_at,updated_at

Field of product_images Table: id,product_id,product_image,created_at,updated_at

products table has OnetoMany relationship with product_images table.

So in the Product model I have defined :

```
public function productImage()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product_image::class,'product_id');
}
```

Now I want to to get all the data of product id 1 from both tables.

So I have this code below:

App\Product::find(1)->productImage

Result Set is:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#689
     all: [
       App\Product_image {#679
         id: 1,
         product_id: 1,
         product_image: "1494787942_download (1).jpg",
         created_at: "2017-05-14 18:52:22",
         updated_at: "2017-05-14 18:52:22",
       },
     ],
   }
```

But I am not getting the product_name. What will be the solution?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`productImage` doesn't have a `product_name` property, but `product` does. When you show the results of `App\Product::find(1)->productImage;` you can't expect it to show a `product_name` property.

If you wanted to see the `product` and it's attached image, you would do this:

```
$product = \App\Product::with(["productImage"])->find(1);
```

Then, doing a `dd($product)` would show you the `product` (including the `product_name` attribute) and the `productImage` as an attribute that returns a `Collection` of `productImage` records.

Keep in mind that have a function named `productImage` that returns multiple `productImage` records is misleading; naming convention would suggest `productImages()`.